# Start another activity WITHOUT clicking a button

Tags: android

I have a problem about create activity in android studio.

- How to start second activity in android studio without clicking button on first activity?

What i means here is, my first activity show my application name, and then it will automatically proceed to next activity without clicking button. 
I've look into many tutorial, but all of the tutorial are using button to go to the next activity...can someone help me..? i really don't know. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `Handler.postDelayed`.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //start new activity here
        }
    }, 2000); //2000 is time delayed in millseconds
```

Comment: where do i have to put this code? sorry, i am a beginner.

Comment: u can just put it in `onCreate`

Comment: i don't find where is onCreate.